# How to batch request with AFNetworking 2?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So I'm rewriting an app for iOS 7 with AFNetworking 2.0 and I'm running into the issue of sending a batch of requests at once and tracking their progress. In the old AFNetworking there was the `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:` method on `AFHTTPClient`, this is clearly refactored out and I'm a bit confused on how to enqueue multiple requests.

I have created a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` and I'm using the `POST:...` and `GET:...` methods to communicate with the server. But I can't find anything in the code and/or docs to enqueue multiple requests at once like with the old `AFHTTPClient`.

The only thing I can find is the undocumented `batchOfRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:` method on `AFURLConnectionOperation`, but that looks like the iOS 6 way of doing this.

Clearly I'm missing something in the new `NSURLSession` concept that I should use to batch requests or looking over a new AFNetworking feature. Hope someone can help me on the right track here!

**tl;dr:** How can I send a batch of requests with my `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass?

Comment: AFHTTPSessionManager implements AFURLSessionManager which implements four important delegates. NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate. NSURLSessionDataDelegate is the most commonly used for GET/POST. Since we singleton the sessionManager, you just need to override these methods.For eg. one of the callback for completion task is - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
...
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Thanks Sendoa for the link to the [GitHub issue where Mattt explains](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1504) why this functionality is not working anymore. There is a clear reason why this isn't possible with the new `NSURLSession` structure; Tasks just aren't operations, so the old way of using dependencies or batches of operations won't work.

I've created this solution using a `dispatch_group` that makes it possible to batch requests using `NSURLSession`, here is the (pseudo-)code:

```
// Create a dispatch group
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Enter the group for each request we create
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    // Fire the request
    [self GET:@"endpoint.json"
       parameters:nil
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                  // Leave the group as soon as the request succeeded
                  dispatch_group_leave(group);
          }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                  // Leave the group as soon as the request failed
                  dispatch_group_leave(group);
              }];
}

// Here we wait for all the requests to finish
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do whatever you need to do when all requests are finished
});
```

I want to look write something that makes this easier to do and discuss with Matt if this is something (when implemented nicely) that could be merged into AFNetworking. In my opinion it would be great to do something like this with the library itself. But I have to check when I have some spare time for that.

Comment: What if the first iteration leaves the group before the second iteration enters it?

Comment: That's not a problem. In that case the for-loop is still blocking the thread. So it will append all other requests to the group, only after the for-loop completes `dispatch_group_notify()` will be called and once all "iterations" leave the group the block is called.

Comment: I am a little new to objc/afnetworking stuff. What is the `self` object here? Its not `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

Comment: Unfamiliar with GCD, but do you have to release the group after you're done?

Comment: If I'm right ARC will handle the release/retain of the group.

Comment: How would you go about making the requests concurrent? i.e. using (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptal/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5 - A concurrent dispatch queue

Comment: Doesn't it have to `dispatch_release` inside `dispatch_group_notify` to release the empty group?

Answer (score 3):

Just updating the thread... I had the same problem and after some researches I found some good solutions, but I decided to stick with this one:

I am using the project called [Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS). So, for the same sample above posted by @Mac_Cain13, it would be:

```
[[BFTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    BFTask *task = [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        task = [task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            return [self executeEndPointAsync];
        }];
    }
    return task;
}] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    // Everything was executed.
    return nil;
}];;

- (BFTask *) executeEndPointAsync {
    BFTaskCompletionSource *task = [BFTaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource];
    [self GET:@"endpoint.json" parameters:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        [task setResult:responseObject];
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        [task setError:error];
      }];
    }];
    return task.task;
}
```

Basically, it's stacking all of the tasks, waiting and unwrapping until there is no more tasks, and after everything is completed the last completion block is executed.

Another project that does the same thing is RXPromise, but for me the code in [Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) was more clear.

Answer (score 3):

For `request` which can be `post` or `get`, you can use `AFNetworking 2.0` for batch operation as firstly you need to create operation like this:

```
//Request 1
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your url here"];
NSLog(@"scheduleurl : %@",strURL);
NSDictionary *dictParameters = your parameters here
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:strURL parameters:dictParameters error: nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationOne = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operationOne = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[operationOne setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
     //do something on completion
} 
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
     NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}];

//Request 2
NSString *strURL1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your url here"];
NSLog(@"scheduleurl : %@",strURL);
NSDictionary *dictParameters1 = your parameters here
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:strURL1 parameters:dictParameters1 error: nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationTwo = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request1];
operationTwo = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[operationTwo setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
     //do something on completion
} 
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
     NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}];

//Request more here if any
```

Now perform batch operation like this :

```
//Batch operation
//Add all operation here 
NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:@[operationOne,operationTwo] progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations)
{
    NSLog(@"%i of %i complete",numberOfFinishedOperations,totalNumberOfOperations);
    //set progress here
    yourProgressView.progress = (float)numberOfFinishedOperations/(float)totalNumberOfOperations;

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) 
{
    NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

On AFNetworking 2.0, `AFHTTPClient` has been split on `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and `AFHTTPSessionManager`, so probably you could start with the first, which has `operationQueue` property.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `NSURLSession` tasks are not suitable for the same kind of patterns request operations use. See the answer from Mattt Thompson [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1504) regarding this issue.

Direct answer: if you need dependencies or batches, you'll still need to use request operations.