# Downloading a large number of images (1500+) efficiently with AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, batch-processing, afnetworking-2

I am building an app that downloads a large number of images, sometimes 1500-5000 images depending on what the user requests. To do this, I am using `AFNetworking 2`. At first, I was just looping through all of my URLs and then making a request for each one.

```
for (NSString *url in urls) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        completion(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure(error);
    }];
    [requestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        double percentDone = (double)totalBytesRead / (double)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        progress(percentDone);
    }];
    [requestOperation start];
}
```

But, after I got to about 900 downloads/requests I would start to get the following error:

```
The request timed out
```

I am assuming this error came directly from `AFNetworking`.

**What is the best and most efficient way to make a large number of download requests like this without timing out? Should I be using `dispatch_group` to batch the requests as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414486/how-to-batch-request-with-afnetworking-2)?**

**Or, should I use a recursive method that will download one image at a time, and only start the next request once the first one finishes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setTimeoutInterval:600];  /* 10 minutes */
```

But it would be best solution if you just download an archive of images and then unpack it.

Comment: In this situation, an archive of images is not possible.

Comment: Is it safe to set such a long timeout interval?

Comment: @NicHubbard Yes, it's safe. By default AFNetworking has 60 seconds timeout interval.